# Filter plugin can no longer be found when using ansible collections

Tags: ansible, ansible-role, ansible-collections

I have a repository I am using to host an ansible collection, it contains an example task within the t1 role, using a custom filter plugin I have created:

```yaml
---
# tasks file for t1
- name: "something"
  debug:
    msg: "{{ 'this is a message' | something }}"
```

Within the collection as follows

```
.
├── docs
├── galaxy.yml
├── meta
│   └── runtime.yml
├── plugins
│   └── README.md
├── README.md
├── roles
│   └── t1
│       ├── defaults
│       │   └── main.yml
│       ├── files
│       ├── filter_plugins
│       │   └── filter.py
│       ├── handlers
│       │   └── main.yml
│       ├── meta
│       │   └── main.yml
│       ├── README.md
│       ├── tasks
│       │   └── main.yml
│       ├── templates
│       ├── tests
│       │   ├── inventory
│       │   └── test.yml
│       └── vars
│           └── main.yml
└── run_role_locally.yaml
```

When I run the `run_role_locally.yaml` playbook - all works as expected.  I am very happy that my filter_plugin is "packaged" within the role.

```py
class FilterModule(object):

    def filters(self):
        return {
            'something': self.something_method
        }
    
    def something_method(self, message):
        return f"{message}, never gonna give you up"
```

Thus

```bash
PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [t1 : something] ************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "this is a message, never gonna give you up"
}

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

However to keep these things decoupled, I have another repository I am using to use the collection as follows:

```
.
├── playbook.yaml
├── README.md
└── requirements.yaml
```

I install the collection successfully, and locally in an adjacent folder

```
ansible-galaxy collection install -r requirements.yaml -p ./collections
```

```yaml
---
collections:
  - name: https://github.com/my_stuff/platform_collections.git
    type: git
    version: release/0.0.0
```

When I run my playbook:

```yaml
---
- name: demo
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  become: false

  roles:
  - role: platform.test.t1
```

Ansible can no longer find the filter plugin:

```bash
PLAY [demo] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [platform.test.t1 : something] **********************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while templating string: Could not load \"something\": 'something'. String: {{ 'this is a message' | something }}. Could not load \"something\": 'something'"}

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Must I relocate the filter plugin to a filter directory or can I keep it within the role?  I have attempted both unsuccessfully.

Comment: You have to fully qualify `something` if it is in a collection. `{{ 'this is a message' | platform.test.something }}`, like you did for your role.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to solve the problem of having the filter within the
```
plugins/filter
```

but it seems to still have trouble finding the filter within the role itself?

Comment: Your filter should be in the plugins folder, see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_collections_structure.html#collection-directories-and-files and https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_collections_structure.html#plugins-directory